# compatibility null pointer error?

Tags: java

```
int e=0;
int Compatibility=0;
int numOfDisagreements=0;
int tsize=likes.size()+dislikes.size();
int numOfCommonLikes=0;
int numOfCommonDislikes=0;
while(e<tsize){
    if (user.likes.get(e).equals(Stranger.likes.get(e))){
        if ((Stranger.howDoYouLike(likes.get(e)))== 1 && user.howDoYouLike(likes.get(e))==1)
        {
            numOfCommonLikes=numOfCommonLikes+1;
        }
    }
    else if (user.dislikes.get(e).equals(Stranger.dislikes.get(e))){
        if ((Stranger.howDoYouLike(dislikes.get(e)))== -1 && user.howDoYouLike(likes.get(e))==-1)
        {
            numOfCommonDislikes=numOfCommonDislikes+1;
        }
```

Am getting a nullpointer error, I don't know what that means but can someone tell me what is wrong with this code please, I am looking real hard

```
    else 
    {
        numOfDisagreements=numOfDisagreements+1;
    }

        e+;
    }

    Compatibility=(numOfCommonLikes+ numOfCommonDislikes)- numOfDisagreements;
    return Compatibility;
}
```

Comment: Post (add to your question) exception description and full stack trace.

Comment: And identify the line that is getting the exception.

Comment: dont understand what you guys saying

Answer (score 0):

Are you initializing you Lists? I see the line:

```
int tsize=likes.size()+dislikes.size();
```

But no proof that you ever created any list objects. A NullPointerException is when you try to use an object that has not yet been created. For example, if I tried to do this:

```
List<Object> objects;
objects.size();
```

Then I would get a NullPointerException. I would need to create the list like so:

```
List<Object> objects;
objects = new List<Object>();
```

Before I tried to call any method belonging to it.

Comment: ok but now am getting a java.lang.stackoverflowerror: null error

Comment: Hmm. I'm not sure. Can you post all of your code so I could see if there is anything else I have missed?

Comment: public class Person
{
    String lastName="";//stores lastname
    String firstName="";//stores firstname
    char sex;//stores sex
    Preference a,d,t;//instances of the Preference enum
    private ArrayList <Preference> dislikes = new ArrayList<Preference>();//dislikes arraylist of type preference
    private ArrayList <Preference> likes = new ArrayList<Preference>();//likes arraylist of type preference
    Person User;//person object called user

Comment: The Person variable you called "user" is never initialized. You never say "user = new Person()" and that is why you get a NullPointerException. The guys who commented on your question were asking you to describe the error message you got.

Comment: am gonna email you something right now and tell me if i am on the right path

Comment: You don't need iterators. You can loop through using a foreach loop. This: for (Preference p : likes)                                                                               /      if (Stranger.dislikes.contains(p))                                                            /             // do stuff

Comment: Ignore the forward slashes I put in the post. I tried to prevent the words from wrapping oddly.

Comment: getting a 'cannot find symbol class Preference' error

here
private Preference a,d,t;

Comment: What line do you get this on?

Comment: line 11 in the code i sent you........private Preference a,d,t;

Comment: Those don't serve any purpose. In the method howDoYouLike(Preference Y), you can just use Y instead of assigning it to t. Although I might be wrong. Please tell me if I am.

Comment: am still getting the same error

Comment: There is no way you are getting the same error on the same line if you deleted that line.

Comment: What line do you get the error on?

Comment: the same line as before

Comment: I do not know what bluej is.

Comment: Can you resend me the source? Maybe you changed something I'm not aware of.